# Google API, unable to update self RSVP status for outlook Invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API to update my RSVP status,
it works fine if its a google invitation, but if the invitation is an outlook, then its throwing following error

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "calendar",
            "reason": "forbiddenForNonOrganizer",
            "message": "The operation can only be performed by the organizer of the event."
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The operation can only be performed by the organizer of the event."
    }
}
```

[this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) is the google api link, where "attendees[].responseStatus" is the property that represent's the RSVP status

I am working with "Ruby on Rails" following is the code for updating the event.

```
def update_event(event)
  auth = set_google_auth(calendar)
  @client.update!(auth)
  service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
  service.authorization = @client
  attendees_array = [
    {
     # This is the authenticated user, where i am trying to update rsvp
     "email": "user_one@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "tentative"
    },
    {
     "email": "other_user@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
  google_event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
    ...,
    'attendees': attendees_array,
    ...
  })
end
```

and set_google_auth method

```
def set_google_auth(calendar)
  auth = Hash.new
  auth["access_token"] = linked_calendar.access_token
  auth["expires_in"] = 3600
  auth["token_type"] = "Bearer"
  return auth
end
```

the user who is updating the event is currently authenticated with google i.e, he/she is updating the status for his/her own calendar.

Comment: can you provide the code where you attempt to set the status?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to call the update also who is the user that is preforming the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using patch and only modifying the attendee status. Otherwise your new event might not contain exactly the same values as the original and the server will think you are trying to modify those as an attendee which will fail.

I've verified that this works for invitations from Exchange in the API explorer.

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/<event_id>?sendUpdates=all&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "email@email.com",
   "self": true,
   "responseStatus": "tentative"
  }
 ]
}
```